# An Excel formula or custom function for an unknown relating to 2 knowns

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible for a formula or custom function in cell C1 using the values in A1 and B1.
Cell A1 has a value of 2600.
Cell B1 has a value of 25 (format percentage).
Cell C1 has a value of 3467.
Cell D1 has a formula of =C1-A1 with a result of 867.
Cell E1 has a formula of =D1/C1 with a result of 25 (format percentage).
I am at present changing the value in cell C1 until the required 25% is achieved in cell E1.
I hope this makes sense, thank you for reading.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.

Comment: do a search on goal seek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in cell C1:

```
=A1/(1-B1)
```

Comment: Thank you. That works a treat. An alternative to using Goal Seek.